# How can I retrieve anti-forgery tokens in a JavaScript function if cookies have the HttpOnly header set?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, antiforgerytoken

I have a web application I am writing on the ASP.NET MVC 4.7 framework and I am trying to properly add anti forgery tokens to my JavaScript AJAX calls.

I am learning from OWASP and Microsoft documentation.
According to this article from Microsoft, the best way to prevent CSRF in AJAX is with anti forgery tokens.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks

In my application currently, when there is a form submission, a JavaScript function is called to handle the AJAX call to my API. If JavaScript is disabled then a regular http request is made to a C# function which also uses AJAX to call the API.

The article shows a bit of C# code which can retrieve the token so it can be passed with the AJAX call. The problem I am running into here is that in order to mix C# and JS functions they use the razor syntax and inline-scripting.

I don’t use inline-scripting for security reasons, and I also have the HttpOnly header set for all cookies. So, to avoid inline-scripting, these JavaScript functions are running in a separate .js file which means I can’t use any C# code to retrieve the token. Also, because of the httpOnly header on the cookies, I do not believe I can retrieve the token using pure javascript.

Passing and validating the tokens works fine with the c# implementation, but I don’t see a way to do this in javascript.

Can someone tell me where I am wrong? Or what I am missing?

If there’s nothing that can be done about this then I may have to completely delete the JavaScript submit functions, but this would mean client side validation would be limited.

Thanks ahead of time for any assistance.

(P.S.) I can’t just pass the token to a JavaScript function for two reasons.

One, I don’t want to pass the token as a plain text parameter in the webpage because then the token would always be plain text in the html.

Two, I am not using “OnClick” at all as that is seen as lining-scripting. This is working off of listener events so I can’t exactly pass a parameter to the function anyways.

Comment: The link you provided is from  2012.  It is old and outdated.  If you use HTTPS (secure) which encrypts the Request/Response with TLS authentication the headers are encrypted and is not prone to attack.  Just make sure the tokens are in the encrypted HTTP headers and not part of the URL parameters.

Comment: @jdweng, I am not worried about the headers being prone to attack here, sorry if I misexplained things. Basically what I am asking is if there is a way to retrieve it from the headers using JavaScript instead of C# because I need to make these ajax calls in JS as well. (I am already retrieving the token successfully when using c# but the c# method is only a backup because it requires page to reload on every single form submission)

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript